# How to use Hibernate in Java without a fixed Mapping to POJO

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a requirement where I have to create a DB Utility for my team.
This DB Utility will take 2 parameters:

1. Path of SQL file where complete query is written.
2. Output path of CSV file where we want to dump the result.

(Assuming host IP and DB Name is already handled)

How can this be achieved by using Hibernate since we do not know the fields and tables being used within SQL file.

Comment: With JDBC, you can get the resulset's metadata to find the returned columns.

Comment: Hibernate is not ideal for this, as Arnaud said, you can use JDBC.

Comment: Any suggestion to ensure Performance while using JDBC.
Since it will be an open Utility, so if someone executed a query with Huge No. of Records, then how to optimise the performance.